# How can I connect my laptop to monitor wirelessly

Tags: display, hdmi, bluetooth, vga

HDMI port on my laptop is dead, It doesn't have VGA port either. How can I connect a laptop to monitor

Comment: Using another computer you could try a remote desktop, but then why not just use the other computer. Or maybe a screencast - are you trying to watch videos on a smart tv or similar? Probably best to just repair or replace the HDMI port

Comment: I am a programmer and I need another monitor apart from laptop screen to work. My monitor support HDMI and VGA input.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a USB video adapter.  They're normally easy and relatively inexpensive to get in most places.  Just look for one which matches one of the inputs on your monitor.

Because your need is based on development, bandwidth shouldn't be too much of a problem unless you're hoping for super-high resolutions. (Games would definitely be out).

Depending on your OS, there may also be wireless display adapter hardware available, but these connections can be less reliable.